# Communication between a flutter web app and a flutter mobile app with bluetooth

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I have a flutter web app A running on chrome on a desktop.
I have a mobile flutter app B running on my cell phone.

I'd like A and B to exchange information via Bluetooth.

Currently, I've set up an RPC server in app B on the desktop, and A and B communicate well when B is running on the same PC as A.
So I'd like to reuse this communication but with B on a cell phone and a Bluetooth comm.

I sent this question to the author of `flutter_web_bluetooth` lib and he said

> Blockquote
> The flutter_web_bluetooth library and the web bluetooth it relies on isn't able to create a Bluetooth low energy GATT server. So it isn't able to be findable to the device. And from what I can find out flutter_blue also isn't able to create a GATT server.
> Though I did find this in the Android documentation. I also found that you can use Bluetooth Peripheral mode on iOS. So it is technically possible (I think) you'll have to find (or create) a library for the mobile side though.

With these 2 links:

- https://medium.com/@kakshata12/creating-ios-application-as-bluetooth-peripheral-669404230232
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattServer

Is it possible to manage my need with flutter ?

Comment: GATT normally runs over Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE). BLE is used for applications that do not need to exchange large amounts of data and can run on battery power for years at a cheaper cost. Can you not achieve what you want by both devices being on the same network? That could be by [tethering](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204023) using Bluetooth